# Subdomain mapping through Proxy or DNS?

Tags: nginx, dns, subdomain, reverse-proxy

I have several sites hosted in various domains like `foo.com`, `bar.com`, `baz.com` etc... My use case is to have those available through subdomains of a unique domain like `foo.mydomain.com`, `bar.mydomain.com`, `baz.mydomain.com` etc...

I do know about CNAME records to easily map `foo.mydomain.com` to `foo.com`, but my registrar only allows up to 100 DNS records using their DNS... so I went through several other funky solutions and reduced them to two options so far:

- create one A record that maps all subdomains to a unique IP, like: `*.mydomain.com A 12.34.56.78`. Then at this IP lives a reverse proxy server like nginx that will handle virtual hosts like:

  ```
  server {
    listen   80;
    server_name http://foo.mydomain.com;
    location / {
      proxy_pass http://foo.com
    }
  }
  ```

OR

- create a DNS server and put related nameservers in front of mydomain.com, where I will basically have the ability to create more than 100 subdomains.

I am starting to think about **performance vs costs vs stability**. DNS is just what I would need in functionality (I don't need rate limiting, load balancing or else: just pure address mapping) but I have been told DNS might be unmanageable/slow as CNAME records list scales (like after 200 CNAME records, things might get slow), is it true ?

The nginx/reverse proxy route seems more robust but most of the time, it will come at higher price while providers tend to bill bandwidth usage and, correct me if I am wrong, but I understand that bandwidth transit in and out nginx, right ? So I will basically pay bandwidth twice : once to get all sites out of host provider, then once again to get it out of Nginx (am I correct ?)

At the end of the day, I just want to achieve the exact same functionality as wordpress, tumblr, blogger etc... that seem to have unlimited number of subdomains to power each of their users websites: user1.tumblr.com, user100000.wordpress.com etc...

What would you recommend to get the same functionality ? proxy or DNS ?
Eventually, I'd like to get this on the cheap side as I have no intention to generate revenues for this project :)

Comment: You already have the clear picture :); just change DNS service provider.

Comment: @DusanBajic I definitely would but I am a bit concerned about performance of having say 100.000 subdomains or more managed as individual DNS CNAME records: do you have any experience with this ? Do you think latency to "find the correct" CNAME rule amongst the 100.000 ones will not become critical ?

Comment: What is an acceptable latency (once you decide, we can run an experiment :) ?

Comment: I reached out some DNS providers like clouDNS.net and the say there is no difference while using 100.000 CNAME or just 1... So I might just go this route.

Answer (score 3):

**In your use case, I'd pick a DNS.**

The Reverse Proxy will have three drawbacks:

- The traffic of *all* subdomains will pass through the proxy, so you might need more than one depending of your traffic
- If the proxy and the webservers are hosted by different providers, latency will increase noticeably
- If the proxy is down, so are all connected subdomains, except if you have multiple load balanced proxies

The DNS doesn't have any of these drawbacks. Reverse Proxies of course have other advantages, but I don't think it's relevant in your use case.

Answer (score 1):

**Reverse Proxy Server**

Creating a lot of records may not be effective so I recommend you the wild card dns way. 
You can create a wildcard record `*.domain.com` which will point to your web server.

It's true that the bandwidth transfer will be doubled.
Reverse Proxy Server (NGINX in this case) will connect to the origin server and download the response, then the same response will be transferred by the this server to the client.

**DNS**

You can host the DNS yourself but that comes at the cost of maintaining the DNS. You can also use a hosted DNS provider (example: AWS ROUTE53) and create CNAME records for yourdomain.com pointing to the origin servers.

**My preference?**

I would go with the reverse proxy server way.

Comment: Hey ! Thanks for the answer. I don't know if I understood correctly, you say: "Creating a lot of records may not be effective so I recommend you the wild card dns way." then "I would go with the reverse proxy server way.". So... what do you recommend for say 100.000 subdomain mapping ? proxy or DNS ?

Comment: If you are fine with creating the dns records for each subdomain, than you will be fine with the "DNS" way. 

I chose the Proxy way in a recent project since maintaining a lot of dns records was not effective for us.

So it depends on your use case, if it's easy for you to create / maintain dns records, you can go with DNS.